# Is there a mode to use Select instead this while loop?

Tags: filtering

I've a list where a I want to pick up my first element which matches my criteria. This is my work around:

```
While[n < Length[listRedPoint],
    If[Sign[listRedPoint[[n]].Take[w, 2] + w[[3]]] != -1, 
    wrongData = {listRedPoint[[n]], -1};
    Break[]
    ];
    n++
];
```

where `listRedPoint` is a  list of `m` pairs `{x_n,y_n}`, `w` is a 3-dimension vector
wrongData is the data picked up.
In general is there any way to optimize this search-algorithm without use while loop? (`Select[]`?)

Comment: It seems `Select` can do what you want, have you tried to use it?

Comment: I've tried `Select[listRedPoint,Sign[#.Take[w, 2] + w[[3]]] != -1,1]` but i got an error....

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SelectFirst` instead of `While`-`Break`.

```
SelectFirst[listRedPoint,
 Sign[#.Take[w, 2] + Last[w]] > 0 &]
```

Comment: i suggest also `SelectFirst[listRedPoint,
 Sign[#.Take[w, 2] + Last[w]] > 0 &,1]` for users with version <10....